# missing argument to `-exec' with `find` in Cygwin

Tags: find, cygwin

I'm new to Linux and trying to work with `rsync`.

I want to sync only file/folders that are created or modified in last 1 days or less. I'm using `cygwin` to sync windows files into Linux.

I tried below command:

```
find D:/foo/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec rsync -zaP {} --size-only --delete //network_path_of_remote_server/foo/ \;
```

Output:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I read similar problems from SO, but unable to figure out.

Please help.

Comment: Does the version of Cygwin that you are using have `rsync`? Does the command work with `scp` instead?

Comment: Yes, `rsync` properly works with any other command.

Comment: What happens if you move the `-exec ...` argument to the end? Or enclose the entire -exec command in quotes, like `-exec "rsync -zaP {}"`? (I suspect this is an issue with how the `find` tool is coded to parse the command line args...)

Comment: You'd get that error message if a `;` (or `{}` followed by `+`) argument was missing after `-exec` which is not the case in the line you show here. Are you sure that's exactly how you entered the command? Try running the command again after `set -o xtrace` and post the trace output.

Comment: Are you running that from the cygwin shell (bash?) or from a `CMD.EXE` or `POWERSHELL.EXE` prompt?

Comment: Please check whether your command that produced that error had `\;` at the end or not.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Running from CMD.exe

Comment: `CMD.EXE` is out of scope here, but I'd expect in `CMD.EXE` backslash is not a quoting operator like on Unix shells as backslash is used to delimit path components in Microsoft systems, so you'd need to quote that `;` some other way (assuming it needs to be quoted there, I'm not familiar with MS OSes).

Comment: try `find /cygdrive/d/foo/` instead of  `find D:/foo/`